# what is the best javascript access performance with using window or not

Tags: javascript, performance, scope

I have several modules. and I'm wondering how to declare these modules.

if there are many modules and access each others function,
What is the better way between **'var module'** and **'window.module'**?

and **'window.moule.somefunction'** and **'module.somefunction'** in otherModules function.

for example,

```
// window.menu =
var menu = function(){
  var menus = null;
  // + many other functions, variables

  function init(){
   getMenu();
  };
  function getMenu(){
    menus = $.ajax(...);
  };
  function doOrder(idx){
    var item = menus[idx];
    // window.order.doOrder(item)
    order.doOrder(item);  // access other module
  };
  return{init:init};
}();

// window.order =
var order = function() {
  var someVariable = null;
  // + many other functions, variables

  function init() {
    // initiallize
  };
  function doOrder() {
    // do order
  };
  return {doOrder:doOrder};
}();
```

Comment: I'd prefer `window.module` since it is more explicit.

Comment: In terms of performance, it will make no noticeable difference.

Comment: Why not namespace the modules and have them access that instead?